# Using Power BI to report who HASN'T logged on

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

A little bit of a newbie with Power BI DAX code. I have a log database that has two tables, Connections, and Employees. The two tables have a one-to-many relationship on sEmailAddress. The following DAX code that creates metrics works well in that I get a count of my employees that connect via VPN and I can get a list of those that connect via VPN

```
sVPN Count =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Connections[sEmailAddress] ),
    FILTER ( Connections, Connections[sTarget] = "VPN" ),
    FILTER ( Connections, Connections[sEvent] = "User Logon" )
)
```

```
sVPN Users =
CALCULATETABLE (
    DISTINCT ( Connections[sEmailAddress] ),
    FILTER ( Connections, Connections[sTarget] = "VPN" ),
    FILTER ( Connections, Connections[sEvent] = "User Logon" )
)
```

I am trying to find a method that can provide me a list of employees that DON'T login on any given day.

Answer (score 1):

You are created a Calculated Column/ Measure, but you put calculation that is returning a table of value. If you need only a list of email, then put your code to "New Table". Then just add this newly created column to your visual.

If you need to show this with additional data, then you can create a column with a flag (1/0) based on your relationship.

pseudo using IF

```
Flag = IF(isblank('left side of relationship'), 1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to add a calculated column to your employee table where you use the `[sVPN Count]` measure you've already defined. Then you can identify the employees who haven't logged in by seeing which rows have blank or zero values in that column.

As msta42a notes, a measure can only return a single value, not a table. (This is the reason for the error you are getting.)